# Long-running operation to update an Android appwidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have a widget that needs to perform a potentially long-running operation in `onUpdate()`. Just performing the operation directly resulted in ANR's. To solve this, my first attempt was to create a thread therein. I noticed that the widget would not get updated in some cases. My guess here is that once `onUpdate()` exits, Android may kill the process along with the unfinished thread.

My next attempt was to create an intent service. The widget's `onUpdate()` just starts the intent service, which does the work directly and updates the widget when done. This works, but much to my surprise it appears that `onHandleIntent()` is single-threaded. If I have two widgets, and then both update and start the intent service, they update sequentially ...

The two widgets case is not really important, but I'm just wondering about a best practice for this type of pattern.

To solve the two widgets case I ended up updating all the widget instances with the same data whenever any one of them is clicked. e.g., I perform the long-running process once and apply the results to all the widget instances. In my scenario this doesn't matter, but for many widgets, it might be important not to do that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but much to my surprise it appears that onHandleIntent() is single threaded

Yes.

> if i have two widgets, and then both update and start the intent service, they update sequentially ...

Yes.

> but i'm just wondering about a best practice for this type of pattern.

Your `IntentService` was a fine upstanding solution, IMHO. Remember that Android runs on slow CPUs, with devices with little RAM. Running lots of threads in parallel is generally not a good idea.

> then i'm getting into starting a thread in onHandleIntent(), which requires a wake lock, and it just seems it's getting all too complicated.

Try my [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Comment: okay if i understand you correctly. 1) widget starts intent service to get data and update widget when it's done 2) intent service gets a wake lock, and starts a thread to do the actual work, and then update the widget when it's done 3) when thread finishes, it releases the lock. boy that sounds complicated. why can't i just grab a lock in onHandleIntent() itself?

Comment: @farble1670: Because the device might fall asleep before you get there.

Comment: sorry, i meant grab a lock in onHandleUpdate(), in the appwidget impl. what does sending the request off to an intent service buy me?

Answer (score 0):

make onUpdate call your own function to cycle through the widgets and update them.  Do your async task before the cycle.  You will want two separate actions, one that asks for the update to start, and one that your `IntentService` will broadcast to let the widgets know they are finished.  Hope this helps.

```
    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

private void updateWidget(Context context){
    ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widget);
    updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

private void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final boolean isEnabled = true; //took out code didn't want you to see
    // start intent service here
    for(int i = 0; i< appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent intent = new Intent(isEnabled ? ACTION_TOGGLE_OFF : ACTION_TOGGLE_ON);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget , pi);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, isEnabled? R.drawable.widget_on : R.drawable.widget_off);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, not sure i see how this applies. start from scratch. in onUpdate(), do long running process, then update all the IDs. the long running process can't just run in the onUpdate() thread, that will cause an ANR. so, use an intent service. but this is single threaded, so if multiple onUpdate() calls come in from multiple widgets, resulting in multiple intent service calls, the second widget hangs waiting for the first to finish in the intent service.

Comment: this is why you would call it before you cycle through and update your widgets, you essentially take over the convince google had in place that updates all the widgets for you.  The update function should really only be handling UI changes so you would have a if/else or switch statement to determine what the current action is (start the thread, thread progress, thread finished)

Comment: okay ... my first question that i guess was missed is about starting the thread. if it okay to start a thread in onUpdate() and return? don't i need to grab a lock? will android kill the process after onUpdate() exits? having it start an intent service in stead of a thread seems to prevent the ANR but it doesn't work when there are multiple widgets updating as they will hang waiting for onHandleIntent() to exit. then i'm getting into starting a thread in onHandleIntent(), which requires a wake lock, and it just seems it's getting all too complicated.

Comment: Ifnyounuse an intent service like originally planned it will destroynitself for you